# How to use signals to update another object in Django?

Tags: python, django

What I'd like to do is to increase the points of a card when a ScanEvent instance is created.
I have the following models:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    # some attributes

class Points(models.Model):
    benef_card = models.ForeignKey(Card, related_name='points')
    at_owner = models.ForeignKey(OwnerProfile)
    nb_current_points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class ScanEvent(Event):
    scanned_card = models.ForeignKey(Card)
    scanned_at_owner = models.ForeignKey(OwnerProfile)
    won_points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    # This method is called with a post_save signal to add points to a card
    def add_points_to_card(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        pts = instance.scanned_card.points.get(at_owner=instance.scanned_at_owner)
        pts.nb_current_points += instance.won_points
        pts.save()

# At the end of models.py
signals.post_save.connect(ScanEvent.add_points_to_card,
        sender=ScanEvent)
```

In a simple Django shell, when I try this:

```
card = Card.objects.get(pk=2)
event = ScanEvent(scanned_card=card)
ownr = OwnerProfile.objects.get(pk=1);
event.save() # will call add_points_to_card()
```

I get no error but points are not updated (this is because the signal is not called)
(it works when I override the save() method thought)

Thanks.

Comment: Please show exactly what code you are using to connect the signal.

Comment: Done. Not sure thought it's the right place to connect the signals (but the error does not seem to be related to this).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your models are correct. With a ForeignKey from Points to Card, that means each Card has *multiple* Points instances. So when you have a Card object, you can't access the points directly: `card.points` is a queryset of all the Points objects that are related to this card.

Either you need to determine somehow which related Points is the one you mean, or change your models. Probably using a OneToOne field instead of a ForeignKey would be more appropriate: then you do only have a single Points instance, and `card.points` will refer to that instance as you expect and you will then be able to access its `nb_current_points` value.

**Edit**

The recursion error is because you have attached your handler to the save signal for *all* classes, not just ScanEvent. You should be sure to specify the `sender` parameter when registering it:

```
signals.post_save.connect(add_points_to_card, sender=ScanEvent)
```

Note that you'll need to move those out of the ScanEvent class otherwise you'll get name errors.

Comment: Oh my mistake sorry: I removed some fields to make it easier on StackOverflow, but the ForeignKey is intentional, because a Points instance can exist for each existing ownerProfile (see the updated code).

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Another reason of the recursion was because I saved "instance" instead of "pts". Adding ScanEvent as a sender make me have a `NameError: name 'ScanEvent' is not defined` :(

Answer (score 1):

In your models, a Card may have several Points associated. That is why instance.scanned_card.points is a RelatedManager, not a Point.
Try this:

```
def add_points_to_card(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for points in instance.scanned_card.points.all():
      points.nb_current_points += instance.won_points
```

Comment: Thanks renobryce and @Daniel Roseman This helped me to understand that I called methods on a queryset instead of an object. Now the problem is different (see the updated post)